# overwrite config file in nodejs - best practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Wondering what would be the best practice for my case.
I have a variable I need to set its value on app load and access this value many times across my code. what is the best way to get this value?
Right now I'm just overriding a config file property. Does a global variable is better? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What kind of config file do you use?

Comment: @AdamAzad local

Comment: I posted something that you might find helpful.

Comment: A global variable is NOT better.  This sounds like you should just be importing a module that maintains this value and everywhere that wants this value just imports the shared module so they can get the value.  That's the "node.js modular way".

Answer (score 2):

The priority standard for configs IMHO is:

1. command line parameter
2. environment var
3. local config file
4. global config file

if no cli parameter found, fall to look into environment vars, then local config file, then global

Answer (score 0):

I do this.

1. Put the variable in `.env` file:

   ```
   # .env
   APP_PORT=4000
   ```
2. In my app source code, I create a file named `constants.js`:

   ```
   // constants.js

   import { load as loadEnvVars } from 'dotenv'; // run `npm i dotenv` to install


   // load the .env file content to process.env
   loadEnvVars();

   // export the variables I need
   export const APP_PORT = process.env.APP_PORT || 3000;
   ```
3. I import that file when I need it like this:

   ```
   // server.js 
   import Express from 'express';

   // import the constant
   import { APP_PORT } from './constants';

   const app = Express();

   app.listen(APP_PORT, () => console.log('server deployed');
   ```